# Fire an event when one element is over another

Tags: javascript, jquery

For an example, lets say I drag an element over another element. Is there a way to fire an event when they touch each other?

I'm trying to do this in javascript or jquery.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't post any code, I could just give you an idea on how to approach this issue:

You probably could use the `.offset` method of jQuery (https://api.jquery.com/offset/). You can listen to the drag event and then check the offset of the draggable element against the target element.

Comment: Ah, I was using position originally. I'll give this one a shot.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: sure :) happy to help